# Preciso fazer uma consulta no banco de dados. mySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados, query

Tenho o seguinte banco de dados.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS futebol (
    id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    nome  VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    estado VARCHAR(2) NOT NULL,
    brasileirao INT NOT NULL,
    copadobrasil INT NOT NULL,
    estadual INT NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO futebol
(nome, estado, brasileirao, copadobrasil, estadual)
VALUES
("Flamento", "RJ", 5, 3, 33),
("Palmeiras", "SP", 9, 3, 23),
("Santos", "SP", 8, 1, 21),
("Coríntias", "SP", 7, 3, 27),
("São Paulo", "SP", 6, 0, 21),
("Vasco", "RJ", 4, 1, 23),
("Cruzeiro", "MG", 4, 5, 37),
("Internacional", "RS", 3, 1, 44),
("Grêmio", "RS", 2, 5, 36),
("Águia de Marabá", "PA", 0, 0, 0),
("Águia de Marabá", "PA", 0, 0, 1);
```

E agora preciso fazer essa consulta:
O estado que possui o maior número de títulos no campeonato brasileirão.

Consegui fazer essa query abaixo, mas suponho que não esteja totalmente correta.

```
SELECT MAX(estado) AS Estado, MAX(CampeonatoBrasileiro) AS Títulos
FROM (SELECT estado, SUM(brasileirao) AS CampeonatoBrasileiro
FROM futebol GROUP BY estado) AS Brasileirão;
```

Poderiam me ajudar?

Answer (score 1):

Primeiro determine a quantidade de títulos por estado e depois ordene e pegue o maior.

```
SELECT estado, SUM(brasileirao) AS CampeonatoBrasileiro FROM futebol GROUP BY estado
ORDER BY 2 DESC LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: Dessa forma ele está resultado em todos os estados. Preciso exibir apenas um resultado com o estado e número máximo de títulos.

Comment: Muito obrigado cara, funcionou.

Comment: Se a ajuda dele resolveu o seu problema, coloque como RESOLVIDO